# Could not at custom add-in - link missing

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013, outlook-web-addins

The link "Add a custom add-in" and the whole "Custom Add-Ins" is not visible in Outlook 2013:

[image: No link visible]

Outlook 2016:

[image: Link visible]

How can I install an custom add-in on Outlook 2013?